# Ruby on Rails validation - If model is invalid, then?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have an `EmailContact` with validation, like so:

```
class EmailContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => {:message => I18n.t('validations.errors.models.user.invalid_email')},
            :mx => {:message => I18n.t('validations.errors.models.user.invalid_mx')}
end
```

Here I am validating `EmailContact.email`.

Then I have a `PhoneContact` with no validation:

```
class PhoneContact < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to write something like this:

```
email_contact = EmailContact.create(params)

if email_contact.invalid?
    phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(params)
end
```

Basically, if the `email_contact` can't be created due to validation errors, I should then create a `phone_contact`. How is that possible?

This is what I've tried:

```
    contact = EmailContact.create(:email => 'a')
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
       (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
    ArgumentError: cannot interpret as DNS name: nil

    contact.invalid?
    NoMethodError: undefined method `invalid?' for nil:NilClass
```

`contact` just returns nil in this case...

## EDIT

It may be that this question needs to go a different direction. Just FYI:

```
email_contact = EmailContact.new(:email => 'a')
email_contact.valid? 
ArgumentError: cannot interpret as DNS name: nil
```

`email_contact.valid?` returns an error instead of returning false as I would expect. I am using the `valid_email` gem to do my validation on the model.

Comment: It sounds like the mx validation is the one causing this problem because it can't get the host or ip address from the invalid email address that you're passing it.

Comment: Correct. I think the issue is with how the validation is being done. I'm using a gem `valid_email`. Even doing `email_contact = EmailContact.new(:email => 'a')` and running `email_contact.valid?` throws the same error. It doesn't return true or false, it throws the `cannot interpret as DNS name: nil` error.

Comment: Do you want to do mx validation? It sounds like an overkill to me. If you remove that part, it'll work fine.

Comment: Valid, mx validation may be overkill - I'll probably remove it and use one of the answers below for now, maybe I can look at bringing it back in later if I need it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `#new` and then call `#save` directly.

```
email_contact = EmailContact.new(params)

if !email_contact.save
  phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(params)
end
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but `!email_contact.save` throws an error and doesn't execute the code block within.

Answer (score 1):

Using `invalid?` method, you could do something like this :

```
email_contact = EmailContact.new(params)

if email_contact.invalid?
    phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(params)
else 
    email_contact.save
end
```

In your case, you used `email_contact = EmailContact.create(params)`.

`email_contact` would be set to `nil` if creation fails and you won't be able to call `invalid?` on a `nil` object.
Check for `invalid?` before creating the record in database.